# How to disable future dates in Android Compose Material3 DatePicker?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `DatePickerDialog` with a `DatePicker`, both imported from the `androidx.compose.material3` package. I believe it should be possible to disable future dates with the `dateValidator` DatePicker property but I would appreciate some help with the implementation.

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
fun PastOrPresentDatePicker() {
  val state = rememberDatePickerState()

  DatePickerDialog(
    onDismissRequest = { ... },
    confirmButton = { ... },
    dismissButton = { ... }
  ) {
    DatePicker(state)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't setting the `selectableDates` argument as part of your [`remembeDatePickerState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#rememberDatePickerState(kotlin.Long,kotlin.Long,kotlin.ranges.IntRange,androidx.compose.material3.DisplayMode,androidx.compose.material3.SelectableDates)) call?

Comment: Good shout, @ianhanniballake. I was using the current stable version of the material3 package where `selectableDates` is not available but a `1.2.0-beta01` upgrade has done the trick. Will give it a try!

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question just in case someone else finds it useful.

**TL;DR**

The [rememberDatePickerState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#rememberDatePickerState(kotlin.Long,kotlin.Long,kotlin.ranges.IntRange,androidx.compose.material3.DisplayMode,androidx.compose.material3.SelectableDates)) helper that you would typically use with the `DatePicker` composable accepts `selectableDates` that can be used to allow or disallow certain dates.

### Full example

Make sure you have and alpha or beta version of material3 listed as a dependency in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
  implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-beta01")
}
```

Consider creating the following helper for reuse:

```kotlin
// PastOrPresentSelectableDates.kt
object PastOrPresentSelectableDates: SelectableDates {
  override fun isSelectableDate(utcTimeMillis: Long): Boolean {
    return utcTimeMillis <= System.currentTimeMillis()
  }

  override fun isSelectableYear(year: Int): Boolean {
    return year <= LocalDate.now().year
  }
}
```

Use it in your composable view:

```kotlin
// PastOrPresentDatePicker.kt
@Composable
fun PastOrPresentDatePicker() {
  val state = rememberDatePickerState(
    selectableDates = PastOrPresentSelectableDates
  )

  DatePickerDialog(/* your params here */) {
    DatePicker(state)
  }
}
```

#### Final product

[image]

Thanks to [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) for providing direction.